# Why would this simple code throw "NoSuchElementException"?

Tags: java, io

`somefile.txt` has some input as below, and `newfile.txt` is empty.

```
China
1330044605
India
1147995898
United States
303824646
```

Both files are on my desktop.

```
public class NextMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File inputFile = new File("/home/cyn/Desktop/somefile.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/home/cyn/Desktop/newfile.txt");


        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

            String coName = in.nextLine();
            int peopCo = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            writer.println(coName);
            writer.println(peopCo);

        }

        in.close();
        writer.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: I fixed your question wording and formatting as best I could. The main other thing missing here is the full exception, including the stack trace and on which line it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to duplicate your problem by adding a blank line to the end of `someFile.txt`.

this is consistent behavior with what's documented in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

> Throws: NoSuchElementException - if no line was found

check to make sure you don't have any unintended whitespace in your input document.